# Why is this class of right-anodyne maps closed under pushouts?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Let $S$ be the class of all right-anodyne maps $r$ such that the pullback of $r$ along any left fibration is again right-anodyne. According to Land's book on $\infty$-categories (specifically the proof of Prp 4.4.16), this class is saturated. (Well, it actually consists of all right-anodyne maps, but that's the final goal of the proof.) As Land notes, it's easy to check that $S$ is closed under retracts and composites, but the same cannot be said for checking closure under pushouts. Unfortunately, Land doesn't give a proof of this, and I haven't been able to find one. I and some of my fellow grad students spent some time trying to prove it with a cubical diagram argument, all to no avail. So, I ask, why is this true?

Comment: The result you want to use is that pushout squares are stable under pullback in the category of simplicial sets. Namely, if I have a cubical diagram of simplicial sets in which the bottom face is a pushout square and all four vertical faces are pullback squares, then the top face is a pushout square.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but there is another proof of 4.4.16.  In https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04887, Moss shows in an appendix that the pullback of an anodyne map along a Kan fibration is anodyne, by a more direct argument (but maybe not an easier argument).  His proof actually applies to 4.4.16 as well.